# Does the week day number changes according to localization in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Does the weekday number changes according to server/database regional configuration in SQL Server (2005+)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weekday number is controlled by the `SET DATEFIRST` setting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

This setting is changed when the `SET LANGUAGE` setting is changed.

```
SET LANGUAGE English;
GO

SELECT 
  @@DATEFIRST as DateFirst,
  CAST('1999-1-1' AS datetime2) AS SelectDate,
  DATEPART(dw, '1999-1-1') AS DayOfWeek;
```

Returns

```
DATEFIRST   SELECTDATE  DAYOFWEEK
7   1999-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 6
```

And

```
SET LANGUAGE German;
GO

SELECT 
  @@DATEFIRST as DateFist,
  CAST('1999-1-1' AS datetime2) AS SelectDate,
  DATEPART(dw, '1999-1-1') AS DayOfWeek;
```

Returns

```
DATEFIRST   SELECTDATE  DAYOFWEEK
1   1999-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 5
```

You can find the `DATEFIRST` setting for each language by querying 
`sys.syslanguages` view and referencing the `datefist` column.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303.aspx